# How to fix the position of an absolute overflowing element with respect to a relative parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I've made a custom select box which is wrapped inside a scroll-able div.

My problem is: the drop down list takes up the space of the wrapper. That is, it appears like this:

[image]

But, I want it to be fixed with respect to the parent wrapper like this:

[image]

I can achieve this result by removing `position:relative;` from  `.select_box`. However, it breaks the spacing between the input box and list (which I don't want) like this:

[image]

Here's my code--

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="select_box">
        <input type="text" onMouseDown="show_list(this)" onblur="hide_list(this)" readonly/>
        <ul style="width:200px;">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br/><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function show_list(element) {
    $(element).next().toggle();
    if ($(element).next().css('display') == 'none') $(element).css('background', 'url(select_box_arrow.png) no-repeat 95%');
    else $(element).css('background', 'url(select_box_arrow_inverted.png) no-repeat 95%');
}

function hide_list(element) {
    $(element).next().hide();
    $(element).css('background', 'url(select_box_arrow.png) no-repeat 95%');
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[class='select_box'] input:text").css("padding", "0 10px");
    $("div[class='select_box'] li").mousedown(function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().attr('value', $(this).text());
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    border:Solid 1px;
    overflow:auto;
}
/* CSS for customized select box */
 .select_box {
    display:inline-block;
    //position:relative;
}
.select_box input[type="text"] {
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:url(select_box_arrow.png) no-repeat 95%;
    font-size:15px;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.select_box input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color:#FFC59D;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #FFC59D;
}
.select_box ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:2px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    border:solid 1px #FFC59D;
    width:220px;
    max-height:250px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000000;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #ff6600;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFC59D;
    scrollbar-face-color: #ff6600;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #ff6600;
}
.select_box li {
    padding-left:10px;
}
.select_box li:hover {
    background:#FF9D5B;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:default;
}
.select_box ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    border:solid 1px #FFC59D;
    border-left-width:2px;
}
.select_box ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background:#FFC59D;
}
.select_box ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background:#FFC59D;
}
```

[**Working fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4rv4s3ce/1/)

Is there a plain CSS solution? I'm open to solutions via jQuery as well.

Comment: put the list in body and use click event to position it. Appending to body is most common approach to avoid overflow problems like this

Comment: @charlietfl That can be tried. But, it seems a strange workaround though. Is there no way I can solve this issue by simple css?

Comment: no, if it is a descendant of an element with hidden overflow there's no way to tell browser to let some of it flow outside, but not the rest

Comment: @charlietfl don't you think I would need to reposition the list with the `scroll` event instead of `click`?

Comment: possibly, i assumed it was like a drop down menu that doesn't show until user clicks to use it

Comment: It is a drop down indeed (which appears on click). However, since the parent div (the wrapper) is scroll-able, I think I need to re-position it as I scroll the wrapper. Remove `position:relative;` from  `.select_box` in fiddle and try scrolling the container (after clicking the text-box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use a native **select** box whenever possible. However, if you have to use a custom list for the input box you could try something like the example below.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rv4s3ce/4/) (you will see I added the native select box next to the text input box to show how it works by default)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-box" style="width:200px;">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
        </ul>
<div id="wrapper">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    <br/><br/>
    <select><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option><option>test</option></select>
    <div class="select_box">
        <input class="list_input" type="text" onMouseDown="show_list(this)" onblur="hide_list(this)" readonly/>
    </div><br/><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function show_list(element) {
    var pos = $(element).offset();
    var input_height = $(element).height();
    $('.list-box').css('top', pos.top + input_height);
    $('.list-box').css('left', pos.left);
    $('.list-box').toggle();
    if ($('.list-box').css('display') == 'none') $(element).css('background', 'url(select_box_arrow.png) no-repeat 95%');
    else $(element).css('background', 'url(select_box_arrow_inverted.png) no-repeat 95%');
}

function hide_list(element) {
    $(element).next().hide();
    $(element).css('background', 'url(select_box_arrow.png) no-repeat 95%');
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[class='select_box'] input:text").css("padding", "0 10px");
    $("ul.list-box li").mousedown(function () {
        $('.list_input').attr('value', $(this).text());
        $('.list-box').toggle();
    });

    $('#wrapper').on('scroll', function(){
        var pos = $('.list_input').offset();
        var input_height = $('.list_input').height();
        $('.list-box').css('top', pos.top + input_height);
        $('.list-box').css('left', pos.left);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    border:Solid 1px;
    overflow:auto;
}
/* CSS for customized select box */
 .select_box {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.select_box input[type="text"] {
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:url(select_box_arrow.png) no-repeat 95%;
    font-size:15px;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.select_box input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color:#FFC59D;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #FFC59D;
}
.select_box ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:2px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    border:solid 1px #FFC59D;
    width:220px;
    max-height:250px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000000;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #ff6600;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFC59D;
    scrollbar-face-color: #ff6600;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #ff6600;
}
.select_box li {
    padding-left:10px;
}
.select_box li:hover {
    background:#FF9D5B;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:default;
}
.select_box ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    border:solid 1px #FFC59D;
    border-left-width:2px;
}
.select_box ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background:#FFC59D;
}
.select_box ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background:#FFC59D;
}
```

**Quick explanation of the changes made:**

As @charlietfl mentioned, the list will need to be appended to the body and not inside the scroll element. From there, I added classes to the input type text and the list, as the parent jquery selector will no longer work as they are not next to each other or in the same parent container. When the input is clicked or the #wrapper div is scrolled I place the list right below the clicked text box.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: scroll demo]

You need to move dropdown menu outside the `#wrapper`, then calculate it's position relative to `input[type=text]` with javaScript and `position: absolute`

working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4rv4s3ce/10/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)